# Black et flickering screen on resume

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, display, amd-graphics

I see this problem around on the internet, but none of the solutions proposed works for me.

I have a lenovo Ideapad on which i install two OS (dual boot fresh installation with nothing in extra)

1. Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop environment , kernel 5.11
2. Arch linux without any graphical program(xorg, gdm, gnome), kernel 5.13.

the module loaded for my card is amdgpu (`lspci -nnk | grep VGA`)

The problem is when booting in ubuntu, resume from suspend works as a charm. But in Arch, resume give a black screen with some flickring on the borders.

- It's software/firmware issue since in ubuntu all works.
- It's related to GPU card since i can type in agetty login (i saw my typing while in black screen on logs ).

If there is no solution known for you, could you suggest to me how to use both distribution to troubleshoot my issue by comparing/copying ?
Also could you guide on how to troubleshoot kernel resume (i believe suspend works)
dmesg does not give a hint to pursue.

Comment: Most likely a driver issue. If you have not added modules (dkms or otherwise), check the kernel versions in the two systems and try to boot the same version. If you have added (graphics card) drivers to one of them, replicate that in the other system.

Comment: But it is booting normally on arch linux. my issue is when i suspend the system (by closing lid for example) and resume (by opening it)

Comment: The code that deals with resume in general and for some devices in particular is in the kernel. It could be another piece of software, but my suggestion is to check the kernel first.